# outer join more than 1 table

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

let's say I have 5 tables, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
CITY NUMERIC,
SALARY NUMERIC);

CREATE TABLE T2 (
CITY NUMERIC,
DISTRICT  NUMERIC);

CREATE TABLE T3 (
DISTRICT NUMERIC,
DOMAIN NUMERIC);

CREATE TABLE T4 (
DOMAIN NUMERIC,
DETAILS_BOOK NUMERIC);

CREATE TABLE T5 (
DETAILS_BOOK NUMERIC,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
EMAIL VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('john', 'doe',1001,1000); 
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('jack', 'jill',1001,2000);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('jeff', 'bush',1001,1500);

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (1001,1);

INSERT INTO T3 VALUES (1,543);

INSERT INTO T4 VALUES (543,22);

INSERT INTO T5 VALUES (22,'john', 'doe','john@22.com');
INSERT INTO T5 VALUES (44,'john', 'doe','john@44.com');
INSERT INTO T5 VALUES (22,'jeff', 'bush','jeff@22.com');
INSERT INTO T5 VALUES (44,'jeff', 'bush','jeff@44.com');
```

now, I want all records from t1, with their salaries and emails, corresponding to tables t2, t3, and t4, such that the reuslt should be:

```
FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | SALARY | EMAIL
--------------------------------------------------
john       | doe       |  1000  | john@22.com
jeff       | bush      |  1500  | jeff@22.com
jack       | jill      |  2000  | (NULL)
```

what I got so far is:

```
SELECT T1.FIRST_NAME, T1.LAST_NAME,T1.SALARY,T5.EMAIL
FROM T1,T2,T3,T4,T5
WHERE   T1.FIRST_NAME = T5.FIRST_NAME (+)
and     T1.LAST_NAME = T5.LAST_NAME(+)
AND     T1.CITY = T2.CITY
AND     T2.DISTRICT = T3.DISTRICT
AND     T3.DOMAIN = T4.DOMAIN
AND     T4.DETAILS_BOOK = T5.DETAILS_BOOK
```

which returns only the first two rows.

Comment: Please go with Mahmoud Gamal's solution. But if you really, really want to use to old syntax, you would of course not to add many more `(+)`. In your case, you need to have one on each line in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Codo Is this really possible using the old syntax? I am getting an error: *a table may be outer joined to at most one other table*, [**when tried to do so**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91d45/20).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just realized that table T5 is joined to both T1 and T4, i.e. you have multi-column outer-join. That's not possible using the old syntax. You have to use the newer ANSI syntax to get your query to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  T1.FIRST_NAME, 
  T1.LAST_NAME,
  T1.SALARY,
  T5.EMAIL
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2  ON T1.CITY         = T2.CITY
LEFT JOIN T3  ON T2.DISTRICT     = T3.DISTRICT
LEFT JOIN T4  ON T3.DOMAIN       = T4.DOMAIN
LEFT JOIN T5  ON T4.DETAILS_BOOK = T5.DETAILS_BOOK
             AND T1.FIRST_NAME   = T5.FIRST_NAME
             AND T1.LAST_NAME    = T5.LAST_NAME;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91d45/1)

This will give you:

```
| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | SALARY |       EMAIL |
-------------------------------------------------
|       john |       doe |   1000 | john@22.com |
|       jeff |      bush |   1500 | jeff@22.com |
|       jack |      jill |   2000 |      (null) |
```

The problem is that the `INNER JOIN` after the `OUTER JOIN` makes your joins works like an `INNER` , because, the inner joins eliminate those unmatched rows coming from the outer joins.

**Note that:** I used the ANSI SQL-92 explicit `LEFT OUTER JOIN` syntax, instead of the old implicit `OUTER` and `INNER` join syntax that you sued in your query.

Please try to use the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of the old outer join syntax, and avoid `INNER JOIN` after `OUTER JOIN`s.

For more details, see these:

- [**Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs.**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).
- [**Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

---

**Update:**

When you have many tables references in the `FROM` clause with the `JOIN` between them, each table is joined with the next table begging from the `FROM` clause<sup>**1**</sup>, results a temporary result set, then this temporary result set is joined with the next table and so on. In case of the  `OUTER JOIN`, there are left or right:

- `LEFT JOIN` will include those unmatched rows from the left table, where as,
- `RIGHT JOIN` will include those unmatched rows from the right table.

Depending on the data you want to select, you have to watch out those tables in the two sides of the `JOIN` operator and the order of them.

---

<sup>**1:**<sup>This is just the logical query processing order, but in the actual order is always up to the query optimizer.</sup></sup>

Comment: Thanks !, but is there a way using the implicit `OUTER JOIN` ?

Comment: @Nati Sorry, I don't know about Oracle, and how implicit `OUTER JOIN` is done.  You can, by `LEFT JOIN` all the same way I do in my answer, and don't do inner join after outer join. it will make it inner join. But try to use the explicit outer join syntax instead.

Comment: +1 for the links and advice. You should also point that the order of joining (when they are outer joins) does matter and may produce diferent result sets. `t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ... LEFT JOIN t5` is not equivalent to `t1 LEFT JOIN t5 LEFT JOIN t2 ...`

Comment: _each table is joined with the next table begging from the FROM clause, results a temporary result set, then this temporary result set is joined with next table and so on_ The results that are returned will be __as if__ that had happened, but actual order is always up to the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 18 (and maybe Oracle 12, but I don't have an instance to test against) you can use:

```sql
SELECT  T1.FIRST_NAME,
        T1.LAST_NAME,
        T1.SALARY,
        T5.EMAIL
FROM    T1,
        T2,
        T3,
        T4,
        T5
WHERE   T1.FIRST_NAME   = T5.FIRST_NAME   (+)
AND     T1.LAST_NAME    = T5.LAST_NAME    (+)
AND     T4.DETAILS_BOOK = T5.DETAILS_BOOK (+)
AND     T1.CITY         = T2.CITY
AND     T2.DISTRICT     = T3.DISTRICT
AND     T3.DOMAIN       = T4.DOMAIN
```

or, equivalently, using ANSI joins (which are considered better practice than comma joins):

```sql
SELECT  T1.FIRST_NAME,
        T1.LAST_NAME,
        T1.SALARY,
        T5.EMAIL
FROM    T1
        INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.CITY         = T2.CITY
        INNER JOIN T3 ON T2.DISTRICT     = T3.DISTRICT
        INNER JOIN T4 ON T3.DOMAIN       = T4.DOMAIN
        LEFT OUTER JOIN T5
                      ON T1.FIRST_NAME   = T5.FIRST_NAME
                     AND T1.LAST_NAME    = T5.LAST_NAME
                     AND T4.DETAILS_BOOK = T5.DETAILS_BOOK
```

Which both output:

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | SALARY | EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | doe | 1000 | john@22.com |
| jeff | bush | 1500 | jeff@22.com |
| jack | jill | 2000 | *null* |

[Oracle 18 Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DlOOA6dz)

---

In Oracle 11g, the first query gives the exception:

```
ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table
```

But the second query (with the ANSI joins) still works.

[Oracle 11g Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GyA0cvzN)